# How to hide the UINavigationBar like the iOS7 Facebook app when scrolling has begun

Tags: facebook, navigation, ios7

The iOS7 facebook app hides the navigation bar (possibly using [UINavigationBar setHidden: animated:]) but it still keeps a solid status bar. What is the best way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Set `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` in the Header (.h) file of the relevant view controller. Add in the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method, and if the `contentOffset.y` is greater than `100`, trigger the UINavigationBar `setHidden:animated` method. Should sort you out. If you want it global, you'll have to access and override it in a UIViewController subclass, or directly access your UINavigationController in your App Delegate.